# Backup & Restore sharepoint 2013 content db on the same server with the different name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, content-database, content-migration

I want to create copy of existing webapplication on the same server.

Can any one suggest me the steps to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot backup and restore the database to the same farm. Each site collection within the farm has a unique ID, which is not changed during the database restore process. Instead you must use `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` which changes the ID of the Site Collection that is restored.

Comment: hi Trevor Seward, thanks for your answer but when I complete restoration of websie I found technical error and when i checked log files it is because of "System.Web.HttpException: The SiteMapProvider 'ListMenuProvider' cannot be found". hav you ever faced this error ?

Comment: That's a different question. Start another thread or edit the other one you have. Make sure to add more information than you did here.

Comment: I already did that at this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196315/sitemapprovider-error-while-backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2013-webstie-on-the-sa

Answer (score 0):

**[Backup-Restore - on the same farm]**

- Take a backup of site collection from the old web application.

  ```
    Backup-SPSite -Identity http://webapplicationURL -Path C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"
  ```
- Create a new web application.
- Restore backup in the new web application.

  ```
    Restore-SPSite -Identity http://newwebapplication -Path "C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"
  ```

---

**In case,** you need to create a copy of existing web application on the same server, you can also `Extend the web application` that you need to make a copy of it by doing the following:

- Open Central Administration –> Application Management –> Manage web applications.
- Select the source web application and from the ribbon click on Extend > then provide the details of the new copy web application.

> **Note:** this to copy the web application and reuse the same content database.
>
> For more details [How to extend a web application in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2011/06/28/how-to-extend-a-web-application-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Is this create a new content db for the extend website or using the same ?

Comment: When I am doing backup restore website using powershell command it give me technical error and managed metadata navigation error

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: The SiteMapProvider 'ListMenuProvider' cannot be found.