# SiteMapProvider error while Backup and restore sharepoint 2013 webstie on the same server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-migration

I have done backup and restore process of sharepoint 2013 website which done successfully.

Now when i am runing website it gives me technical error and when i check log files it gives me Error **The SiteMapProvider 'ListMenuProvider' cannot be found**

Can any one guide me why it is occuring?

Comment: You haven't provided any information for us to help you. How did you perform the backup, what error is presented, what error(s) is in the ULS log, and so on.

Comment: The SiteMapProvider 'ListMenuProvider' cannot be found

Comment: You need to add more information, e.g. a complete ULS log so we can look at it. Just be aware of the PII potentially contained in it (usernames, server names, etc.).

Comment: Did you restore the site within the same farm, web application etc. And were there any custom solutions that were targeted at the site collection level, it could be that the features are required to be activated etc.Also the URL within the MasterPage could be hard coded, however as Trevor Seward mentioned you need to provide more info for us to help.